# how values corresponds to columns in PCA explained_variance_ratio_?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I have some dataframe `df` and want to use explained_variance_ratio_ on it.

```
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
Y_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_std)
pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

And as a result I get something like this:

```
array([0.3894487 , 0.25278034, 0.16070989, 0.10005305, 0.07093894,
   0.02606909])
```

The problem is that if I swap columns the result of  `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` is still the same. So how can I how values corresponds to columns?

Comment: Which columns are you talking about when swapping? Input features? `explained_variance_ratio_` will be equal to the number of output components from PCA, not input.

Comment: Indeed, the *order* of input columns has nothing to do with the calculation of the principal components

Answer (score 0):

PCA is **invariant** to **permutation** of the **feature** / **variable** (columns).

The values that you get from `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` is the ratio of the explained variance of each `component`.

```
array([0.3894487 , 0.25278034, 0.16070989, 0.10005305, 0.07093894,
       0.02606909])
```

Since, there are 6 values in `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` it means that the `n_components` was 6.

**These values correspond to the principal components/axis** and you can see that **PC1 explains 38.9 %**, **PC2 explains 25.27 %** of the **variance** e.t.c.